# How to insert node at the end of the Range?

Tags: javascript, range

I want to insert a node at the end of the selection range, but according to API docs here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range the Range.insertNode() inserts the node at the start of the range and there is no other method to insert at the end, is there a way to add the node at the end of the range object?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing GiorgiosJames's answer working as it places the node after the end of the start container rather than at the end of the selected range.

I how about using the following:

```
const insertAtEnd = (myRange, nodeToInsert) => {
   const myRange2=myRange.cloneRange();
   myRange2.collapse(false); // collapse the range to the end of selection
   myRange2.insertNode(nodeToInsert);
};
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/9zjcgbku/ for a working version of both Giorgios and my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just save the range's current position, set the start to the end of the current range, insert your node, then set the range back.

```
// assuming..
const myRange = document.createRange();
const startNode = document.getElementById('startNode');
const endNode = document.getElementById('endNode');
const nodeToInsert = document.getElementById('insertNode');

myRange.setStart(startNode, 0);
myRange.setEnd(endNode, 0);

// then..
const insertAtEnd = (myRange, nodeToInsert) => {

    const oldStart = myRange.startContainer;

    const oldEnd = myRange.endContainer;

    myRange.setStartAfter(oldStart);

    myRange.insertNode(nodeToInsert);

    myRange.setStart(oldStart, 0);
    myRange.setEnd(oldEnd, 0); 


};

insertAtEnd(myRange, nodeToInsert);
```